# Failed to build when using fragment testing library on AndroidGradlePlugin 3.5.0 and above for Dynamic Feature module

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, android-testing, android-fragmentscenario

So, I was trying to use fragment testing library `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.4` in a dynamic feature module. When I used Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version `3.6.3`, it failed to build with an error

```
AAPT: error: resource style/FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme (aka com.example.reminder.test:style/FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme) not found.
```

And so I was curious and checkout the [codelab github](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing) and try to upgrade the AGP on that project to `3.6.3` and it can build successfully. But the codelab does not use Dynamic Features.

So I tried to actually run a fragment test in my `app` module only (excluding the dynamic features module) and yes it can build successfully too.
But I still need to test my fragment in the dynamic features module, so I tried playing with the version one by one and then when I downgrade the AGP version to `3.4.1` it can build successfully.

And I found out that since AGP version `3.5.0` and above, it just failed to build with the same error above.

So,

```
AGP 3.5.0 and above:
- Building test on app module only -> works
- Building test on dynamic features -> failed to build

AGP 3.4.2 and below:
- Building test on app module only -> works
- Building test with dynamic features -> works
```

But I still want to use AGP `3.6.0` because I want to utilise viewBinding.

So does anyone know how to resolve the error above for fragment testing with dynamic features module?

Comment: Getting the same error. I've created an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157498388

Comment: Hi, thanks for creating the issue. I thought I was the only one getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading AGP to `4.0.0` and above should resolve the issue.